# How to unnest a json arrays columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a column called `event_params` with values like this:

```
[{"key": "label", "value": {"int_value": null, "float_value": null, "double_value": null, "string_value": "example"}}, {"key": "label2", "value": {"int_value": null, "float_value": null, "double_value": null, "string_value": "another_example"}}, {"key": "label3", "value": {"int_value": 9, "float_value": null, "double_value": null, "string_value": null}}, {"key": "label3", "value": {"int_value": 1234, "float_value": null, "double_value": null, "string_value": null}}]
```

OR

```
[{"key": "label",
  "value": {"int_value": null,
            "float_value": null,
            "double_value": null,
            "string_value": "example"}},
  {"key": "label2",
   "value": {"int_value": null,
            "float_value": null,
            "double_value": null,
            "string_value": "another_example"}},
  {"key": "label4",
   "value": {"int_value": 9,
            "float_value": null,
            "double_value": null,
            "string_value": null}},
  {"key": "label4",
   "value": {"int_value": 1234,
             "float_value": null,
             "double_value": null,
             "string_value": null}}]
```

I would like to unnest this column to extract the `string_value` from `key` = "label" for every `user_id`. To do that I'm trying to use `jsonb_to_recordset` function but the output I'm getting is basically the same user_id but multiple times and the only thing it changes it's the values from each "value" key:

```
user_id | value
123 | {"int_value": null, "float_value": null, "double_value": null, "string_value": "example"}
123 | {"int_value": null, "float_value": null, "double_value": null, "string_value": "another_example"}
123 | {"int_value": 9, "float_value": null, "double_value": null, "string_value": null}
...
```

All of that for the same user even though there are more users (I would expect to have just one row per user). Here is the piece of code that I'm using:

```
select
    user_id,
    event_params,
    evs.key,
    evs.value::json
from google_analytics.firebase_events_analytics,
    jsonb_to_recordset(event_params) as evs(key text, value text)
```

Comment: where is user_id in your json?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga `user_id` comes from `google_analytics.firebase_events_analytics` table.

Comment: "*from key = "label"*" - well you forgot that `WHERE` condition in your query, so you're getting the values from all keys. Which should be obvious if you really do `select […] evs.key` as you show

Comment: Don't use `value text` and `value::json`, just declare the record field as `value json(b)` right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is returning multiple rows per user_id because of an implicit `CROSS JOIN`. The following is the equivalent when the `CROSS JOIN` is explicitly expressed (the implicit `LATERAL` associated with `JSONB_TO_RECORDSET` is also included):

```
SELECT user_id,
       event_params,
       evs.key,
       evs.value
  FROM google_analytics.firebase_events_analytics
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSONB_TO_RECORDSET(event_params) AS evs(key text, value jsonb)
```

The desired behavior can be achieved by filtering the joined rows. The following uses criteria in the `WHERE` clause to exclude undestired rows:

```
SELECT user_id,
       event_params,
       evs.key,
       evs.value
  FROM google_analytics.firebase_events_analytics
  CROSS JOIN JSONB_TO_RECORDSET(event_params) AS evs(key text, value jsonb)
  WHERE evs.key = 'label';
```

An alternative is to use `JOIN` criteria:

```
SELECT user_id,
       event_params,
       evs.key,
       evs.value
  FROM google_analytics.firebase_events_analytics
  JOIN JSONB_TO_RECORDSET(event_params) AS evs(key text, value jsonb)
    ON evs.key = 'label';
```

The two approaches are equivalent and produced identical explain plans when I tested the queries.

Comment: @bergi, thanks for the cleanup. I was so focused on the core problem I didn't even look at the other issues.